# Default field value with @Builder or @Getter annotation in Lombok

Tags: java, getter, builder, lombok

I'm using Lombok `@Builder` annotation, but I'd like some of the `String` fields to be optional and default to `""` to avoid NPEs.  Is there an easy way to do this? I can't find anything.

Alternately, a way to customize `@Getter` to return a default value if the variable is `null`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Starting from version `v1.16.16` they added `@Builder.Default`.

> `@Builder.Default` lets you configure default values for your fields
>   when using `@Builder`.

**example:**

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
public class MyData {
  private Long id;
  private String name;

  @Builder.Default
  private Status status = Status.NEW;
}
```

*PS:* Nice thing they also add warning in case you didn't use `@Builder.Default`.

> Warning:(35, 22) java: @Builder will ignore the initializing
>   expression entirely. If you want the initializing expression to serve
>   as default, add @Builder.Default. If it is not supposed to be settable
>   during building, make the field final.

Comment: It is not nice at all! If you use `@Default.Builder` **and** `@NoArgsConstructor` (I know it does not make sense **but** sometimes due to some frameworks you **must** provide no args constructor), the initialiser is **not** used in the default constructor! This is a serious bug.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you; The design of generated code by lombok isn't so nice (Its good idea to check the generated classes). One workaround, to write the no-args-constructor by yourself.

Comment: Sounds like they fixed this in v1.18.2 (July 26th, 2018). FEATURE: NoArgsConstructor now take any defaults set with Builder.Default into account. Issue #1347

Comment: It was NOT fixed. https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2340

Answer (score 4):

You have to provide the builder class like the below:

```
@Builder
public class XYZ {
    private String x;
    private String y;
    private String z;

    private static class XYZBuilder {
        private String x = "X";
        private String y = "Y";
        private String z = "Z";
    }
}
```

Then the default value for `x`, `y`, `z` will be `"X"`, `"Y"`, `"Z"`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to go is to use `@Builder(toBuilder = true)`

```
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class XYZ {
    private String x = "X";
    private String y = "Y";
    private String z = "Z";
}
```

and then you use it as follows:

```
new XYZ().toBuilder().build();
```

With respect to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347012/1339429), this approach is less sensible to class renaming. If you rename `XYZ` but forget to rename the inner static class `XYZBuilder`, then the magic is gone!

It's all up to to you to use the approach you like more.

Comment: you forgot the `()` in `new XYZ()`

Comment: @HazelTroost fixed