# Java builder with automatic defaulting capability in annotated way

Tags: java, lombok, builder

Below is my unconventional builder class. If you observe carefully, in my builder methods, i am setting some default values as per the data type of the field. And in my client code below, i am just constructing the object based on *certain fields (address and age)* only out of *all available fields (firstName, lastName, age, phone, address).* This way, when i parse the User object programatically, i will know what are the fields requested [non-null] and others not requested [null]. Accordingly i can write my logic to do some processing.

Now my exact requirement is :-

Is there such a custom builder or any annotation that will help me achieve this in smart way ? Because i have 100+ java models and each model containing 50+ fields. So, i want to avoid writing these boiler plate code of builder methods (setting default values) and simply use an annotation kind of thing.

**NOTE**:- I want to avoid adding boiler plate code by touching all of these java classes (100+) that i have and simply use some kind of annotation that will help me solve my defaulting problem.

> Builder class definition

```
public class User
{
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;
    private final String phone;
    private final String address;

    private User(UserBuilder builder) {
        this.firstName = builder.firstName;
        this.lastName = builder.lastName;
        this.age = builder.age;
        this.phone = builder.phone;
        this.address = builder.address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User: "+this.firstName+", "+this.lastName+", "+this.age+", "+this.phone+", "+this.address;
    }

    public static class UserBuilder
    {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private int age;
        private String phone;
        private String address;

        public UserBuilder age() {
            this.age = 0;
            return this;
        }
        public UserBuilder phone() {
            this.phone = "";
            return this;
        }
        public UserBuilder address() {
            this.address = "";
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder firstName()
        {
            this.firstName = "";
            return this;
        }

        public UserBuilder lastName()
        {
            this.lastName = "";
            return this;
        }

        public User build() {
            User user =  new User(this);
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

> Client call

```
User user = new User.UserBuilder()
                            .address()
                            .age()
                            .build();
```

Comment: [Didn't you ask this yesterday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68801992/java-builder-with-automatic-defaulting-capability-in-annotated-way) Please do not repost. Undelete and edit the old post instead.

Comment: I think you are looking for [Builder.Default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40314445/7804477). (Also note that the default value of primitive `int` is 0. So no need to provide a default value)